# Inrush current in Apk/us what does it mean

Tags: inrush-current

I'm looking at this LED power driver from a design, and I see it has inrush current speced as 190Apk/400us.    Does that mean there's a 190A spike over 400us.  That seems a little insane, how would ever control something like that to turn it on and off?   Here's the [datasheet](http://www.usa.lighting.philips.com/connect/tools_literature/led_drivers/downloads/150W_0.70A_210V_0-10V_INT_LEDINTA0700C210DO.pdf)

[image]

Or is that just a rate and I have to use something else to determine peak current?

Comment: That is the surge current into the input capacitors when it is first energized.

Comment: If you switch at the zero-cross, you will probably not see a transient like that.

Comment: That looks like a fairly normal peak inrush current. Examine a few bridge rectifier datasheets and note their Issm (surge current) ratings. To pick one low cost  10A one ... 200A for one cycle (>> 400 us) http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1662105.pdf

Comment: So what does that mean though will I see 190A at 277V for 400us if I switched it over at the peak?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the specification is for inrush current.

If you look at section 3.8 of the data sheet you reference, the manufacturer calls for a type CCMR fuse (Little Fuse brand).  LittleFuse mentions "withstand sustained starting currents".

[image]

http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electrical/datasheets/fuses/industrial-and-ul-fuses/littelfuse_fuse_ccmr_datasheet.pdf